# How to Return a matrix 3x30 of users in solidity

Tags: solidity

#### Hi everyone

I have a little complex question about **Solidity**
I have a project that I need to solve a matrix and return a matrix 3x30 of users for example

```
                 1
               1 1 1
            111 111 111
111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111
.......................................
```

how to do this in solidity 
I appreciate any idea 
is this helpful

```
uint256[3][30] downLines;
```

thanks

Comment: Can you please try to explain how this is related to the C programming language?

Comment: sorry for any misunderstanding @Someprogrammerdude it's a little like c so i added c tag

Comment: anyone have any idea?

Comment: @RaminMoradi What is the use case? Do the values need to be unique (across the whole DB, across the parent-children relationship chain)? Can a child element have more than one parent (e.g. one user belongs to more relationship chains)? ... There are many different ways to solve this depending on the context. Please update your question with more context.